# Can have saved login in Firefox only for one Stackoverflow account

Tags: firefox, debian

I have stackoverflow.com, superuser.com accounts. Looks I can't have Firefox ESR 102.11.0esr (64-bit) letting me to login both using saved logins. Let me give an example. Currently I'm logged in to superuser.com (Firefox remember the login/password-s pairs). If I try to login stackoverflow.com,I get the error "The email or password is incorrect." I press "Forgot password?" and follow the instruction to recover the password. After that I can login stackoverflow.com. But no more to superuser.com. Login/password pair for superuser.com now is invalid and I get "The email or password is incorrect." for superuser.com that time. I repeated that a couple of times. I ended up logging in using Facebook account. I clearly remember I could log in many sites using the login/password pairs before.

Using:
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Firefox ESR 102.11.0esr (64-bit)
all updates being installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this from Firefox Mac, but I assume all the platforms are similar…

The Stack Exchange network considers all linked domains as one entity; browsers don't, as just those two SE sites have different TLDs compared to all the others. If you don't have cross-site cookies enabled, then the sites will require separate logins from your browser. It ought to be possible to set your browser to remember both logins as having the same credentials, or just update one saved pw manually to match.

From the burger menu, top right, select Passwords. Select one of your correct entires for Stack Exchange, press Copy, then switch to the other[s] & top right next to the site name select Edit, then paste it to that Password area. Save.

[image]

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Tried several times. Something went wrong with FF or with me. I used Facebook to login to some TLD. Tomorrow with fresh mind I will makes a clear experiment.

Comment: It was tricky but worked. After I updated the password for superuser.com I needed an "extra" login page to to through